# Is it possible to have a certain files in a server to redirect to https and others are forced to only http no matter if you put https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to do this on .htaccess

```
if(filename.php = "order.php"){
  redirect to https
}else{
  redirect to http
}
```

I need it to do something like this, user might want to put https on my index.php and its unsecure and gives an error, that why I need to force to http if its not order.php, and force https if its order.php

I have 3 similar folders like in 1 server,

I tried to use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(order.php) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

but failed, I did it on PHP, but I will have to put all of it hundred files.

So Iguess .htaccess will be more time efficient,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/order.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/order.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Both rules will need an external redirect therefore you need to add `[L,R]` flags for RewriteRule lines.

Comment: Hello Death, I tried that, but the problem is, when I am on order.php right, it will force order.php to https, but all the .js and .css and images will be on http, will result to error on https... any suggestions?

Comment: continuationg ^^ , because of this RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/order.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: @Lj Pearson you can put them relative not absolute! so if page is using https, they will do too!

Comment: Hi Death, I don't want to sound stupid or asking to be spoon fed, but I just don't really get htaccess yet, what did you mean by absolute? also I did not see your comment on Sep15, I did the harder way and did it via PHP, because I have a php script required on all the php files, but I would want to learn via htaccess next time, Thank You

Comment: 1 - what did you mean by **I just don't really get htaccess**?? 2- absolute :**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400928** relative: **../questions/7400928** Second one works if the link is in **http://stackoverflow.com**